# Pixel 2 API 29 httpClient not working correctly

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have finally released a nativescript app to the store. iOS is good, almost all versions of Android are good. However, someone downloaded onto a Pixel 2 with API 29 and told me they couldn't login. I downloaded an emulator and sure enough, the http request never goes through.

This is my login code in my service:

```
getLogin(args): RxObservable<Object> {
    var params = this.buildQueryParams(args);
    let headers = this.createRequestHeader();
    return this.http.get(`${this.serverUrl}AuthenticateUser${params}`);
}
```

This is my login component using it:

```
login() {
  this.isLoggingIn = true;
  Object.assign(this.user, this.loginForm.value);
  this.httpSub = this.httpget.getLogin(this.user)
  .pipe(
    map(res=>res),
    catchError((err: string) => {
      const errMsg = "There was a network error, please check your connection or try again later";
      return of(errMsg)
  })
)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    if(result['Status'] === "SUCCESS"){
      this.onGetDataSuccess(result);
    }
    else if(typeof(result) === 'string'){
      this.errorMessage = "There is a connection error.";
      this.isLoggingIn = false;
    }
    else {
      this.errorMessage = "user name or password incorrect";
      this.isLoggingIn = false;
    }
}, (error) => {
  console.log("got an error");
    this.errorMessage = "Verify your username and password.  If you have an account, but are having trouble, call 1-866-706-8665.";
    this.isLoggingIn = false;
});
```

I'm getting this on the Pixel:

There is a connection error.

In the debugger this is what I see in the Headers on the pixel:

```
Request URL: http://toolingu.com/ToolingU.WCF.TuAppService/ToolingU.WCF.TuAppService.svc/AuthenticateUser?username=<user>&password=<pw>
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
username: <user>
password: <pw>
```

This is what I see on the emulators that are working correctly:

```
Request URL: http://toolingu.com/ToolingU.WCF.TuAppService/ToolingU.WCF.TuAppService.svc/AuthenticateUser?username=<user>&password=<pw>
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
username: <user>
password: <pw>
```

It appears the error happens instantly, as if it isn't waiting for a response to come back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Http communications (clear text traffic) are blocked by default from Android Pie (API 29). You will have to enable it by explicitly by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on `application` tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Like this?   <application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

Comment: Yes, that should be it.